# Limit number of blog entries on front page of site

Tags: php, html, limit, posts

I recently created a blog (php & html). Because I produce lots of new blog entries, it is crucial that I limit the front page to the most recent 10-20 entries.
Does someone know a solution on how to do this automatically? So basically I need to figure out how to limit the number of blog entries that display on the front page. Right now, every blog entry is displaying on the front page, creating a very long first page.

I know it's possible to create multiple pages containing 10 entries each but that's not the solution I am looking for. I always want the most recent blog entries displayed on the front page.

Comment: What you need is _pagination_. Don't fetch all entries at once, but instead limit the query to your data store. Then make the code that displays a list of entries take arguments, like how many entries, and from which one to start. Set default values of _start at 0_ and _10 per page_ and make that your blog's home page.

Comment: As is, this question is describing some buisness logic. That's not really a programming question. You need to break this down to something that can be solved with code: "How do I limit results from SQL?", "How do I get subset of objects containing the most recent items?". We need more context about how your stuff works. VTC - Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select most recent entries, you need to use select data from database in descending order. 
An example of such query is given below...

```
SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY id DESC
```

And for selecting a limited number of entries to display on any page. You need to provide a limit in the query. 
An example of such query is given below...

```
SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

In this case last 10 entires will be selected.

Comment: There is no mention of a database in the question. For all we know, they might have a long text file with all their posts.